# VBScript Windows MediaPlayer

Tags: windows-media-player, vbscript, code

I'm trying to learn VBScript and I can't understand what is wrong with this code. It's supposed to play a midi file and set volume to 100 on the computer. This is in Windows 7 VBScript on Notepad. The problem is that the file runs and doesn't give an error message, but doesn't change the volume or play the midi.

```
set bob= wscript.CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7")                      
bob.settings.autoStart= True                                                     
bob.settings.volume= 100                      
bob.URL= ("C:\Users\9009895\Downloads\test.mid")
```

Comment: So how are you running it? What is the error?

Comment: Don't think there would be an error. If this is his whole script it will just quit real fast and as the WMPlayer Com Object will be destroyed nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

The WMPlayer COM Object that is supposed to play the midi file is destroyed as soon as the script is finished.
So you need to either wait for as long as as the midi file is with:

```
Wscript.Sleep 10000
```

where isntead of 10000 you put (<3 seconds to initialize> + ) * 1000 (for miliseconds)

Or if you want to give the user control over when to stop it:

```
MsgBox "Press OK to stop playback"
```

As for the volume I think this will just set the volume of the WMPlayer app to 100% not the system one. If you want to change the systemvolume you will probably need an additional tool like [nircmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) (more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2216334/how-to-control-windows-system-volume-using-jscript-or-vbscript))